# How does Python keep track of libraries (directories) to import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries

I have two slightly different branches of Python 3 code on my computer. I am frequently switching back and forth between them. Both contain slightly modified files and directories that are named the same way. The code in each directory imports code from a subdirectory, e.g. "from ldm.util import instantiate_from_config", where "ldm" is a subdirectory of the directory I'm currently in, and "util.py" is a file in "ldm."

Python keeps getting confused when I import and using the "util.py" and "ldm" directory from the other branch. Neither branch is on the Windows PATH or PYTHONPATH. I can trick Python by temporarily renaming the directory I don't want to use, but I want to understand: how is Python remembering that this other directory exists to go import it? How can I tell Python that if a folder is a subdirectory of the folder I'm currently in, that's the version I want it to import?

Comment: the files must be unique....  you can specify the full file path to ensure this ?

Comment: How would you specify the full file path in an import statement?

Comment: You could use my experimental import library: ultraimport - It let's you just do that, import any file from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answers:

1. "The first thing Python will do is look up the name abc in sys.modules. This is a cache of all modules that have been previously imported."
2. "The syntax of a relative import depends on the current location as well as the location of the module, package, or object to be imported." So it needs a "." beforehand to tell it to use something from the current location. Example: "from .subpackage1.module5 import function2"
   from https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/